# Bilinear and Quadratic forms: broad classification

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Can one briefly describe the broad classification of bilinear and quadratic forms over arbitrary fields?

Even though classification is incomplete, one may put them into some categories, and say "This category is difficult to classify".

Comment: You probably should be looking for an overview of quadratic forms in _number theory_ rather than in linear algebra. Start at this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_quadratic_form

Comment: This is my area. I don't see that there is much reason to attempt a tutorial on a website. There is quite a bit to know, even with binary forms with integer coefficients. For those, my favorite book is Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms. In turn, he says that he simply modernized Mathews Theory of Numbers, mostly to allow $b$ odd in $a x^2 + b xy + c y^2.$ Beyond that, Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms. For ternary forms and some quaternary, my http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Jagy_Encyclopedia.pdf